# Imacros Type a link click not working

Tags: click, imacros

I'm using Imacros to click on this button:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" data-click="{"id":9553638,"o":"0"}" class="btn btn-primary btn-large click-button">Click</a>
```

using code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"btn btn-primary btn-large click-button"
```

also

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"btn btn-primary btn-large vote-button"&&TXT:Click
```

When running the Imacros code the button only gets selected but not clicked,

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same issue. In my case, it turned out that the  element I wanted to click was in a frame. I opened that frame in it's own tab, grabbed the URL, and told the imacros script to go to that URL before clicking the link. There's probably a simpler solution that involves selecting the frame, but I didn't dig into that.

You can open a frame within a page in a new tab from the right-click context menu.